# Is there a way to create a DEM that follow the point cloud so you don't need to clip the DEM after?

Tags: qgis, dem, clip, interpolation, extract-by-mask

I would like to create a DEM from an XYZ file (gridded 0,25x0,25) with 0,25 cell. I'm wondering if there is a way so that my interpolation follows my point cloud, instead of covering a rectangle like in the below picture. I've tried the output option in QGIS called "Use layer extent", thinking it would use the boundaries of the point cloud and clip it automatically.

So I'm wondering if there is a way so you don't need to mask/clip the raster after the interpolation, so that it follows the edge of the point cloud.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please take a look at the **[Tour]**.
And please also **[edit]** some extra info into the body of the question for clarification:
e.g. you have a set of irregular points?, you wish to create a TIN? but you get a gridded DEM? using what software? Things aren't very clear.

Comment: I have a gridded point cloud 0,25x025 m. I wish to create a DEM raster with same grid/cell size. I'm wondering if there is a way to make this DEM so it follow the point cloud and clip its self and create a raster that only follow the point cloud. Now it creates a rectangle following the max and min extent. 

Is there a way to just create the DEM raster and not mask/clip it afterwards?

Comment: Kindly edit your question.